# Checkbox Fieldtype Conditionals

Tags: ee2, custom-fields, conditionals

How would you perform a conditional on a custom checkbox field in which the user can select 0 -4 different options?

In other words, I have a "Checkboxes" fieldtype named "{side_content_selectables}".

This fieldtype has the following options:

- Show Search
- Show Feed Subscription
- Show Categories
- Show Recent Posts

Which would just allow them to turn widgets on or off. In my template, I have the following:

```
<aside id="sidebar">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="side_content" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
        {if {side_content_selectables}"{item}" == "Show Search"{/side_content_selectables}}
            <section class="widget">
                <h3>Search</h3>
                {!-- Search Form --}
            </section>
            <!-- /.widget -->
        {/if}
```

OR

```
        {if "Show Feed Subscription"}
            <section class="widget">
                <h3>Subscribe</h3>
                {!-- Feedburner Widget --}
            </section>
            <!-- /.widget -->
        {/if}
```

Neither of these seem to work though. This makes me feel like a big noob, but I am stumped on this one.    ;)

It's almost like I would need to write out a PHP script to perform a contains, but that just seems like overkill and I would like to keep PHP from being used in templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're best off using the PT Checkboxes, the native ones are just too fragile for real world use.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pt-field-pack

Then:

```
{if {side_content_selectables:selected option="show_feed"}}
  <p>show the feed</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: exactly what I was going to suggest.

Comment: Thanks James. I usually include those and use them as my default fieldtypes instead of the natives, I just thought I would give it a go on this one. Now I know why I default to P&T.   ;)

Answer (score 2):

I second the answer posted by @James, PT Checkboxes are more flexible, but if you want to use the native checkboxes the following will work:

```
{checkboxes_field}
    {if item == "Option One"}<p>Option one is checked</p>{/if}
    {if item == "Option Two"}<p>Option two is checked</p>{/if}
    {if item == "Option Three"}<p>Option three is checked</p>{/if}
{/checkboxes_field}
```

Just replace the custom field name and option values to match your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be the proper syntax

{if '{side_content_selectables}{item}{/side_content_selectables}' == 'Show Search'}

Comment: that would only work reliably if one and only one option were selected...

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with the native field type and can't switch for whatever reason (legacy data etc) then you can always use the phpstringfun plug-in (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/phpstringfun) and do something along the lines of:

```
{if "{exp:phpstringfun function='substr_count' par1='Foo'}{checkboxes_field}{/exp:phpstringfun}"=="1"}
Foo Found
{/if}
```

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just joined, so I can't comment on the accepted answer, but...

the correct syntax should be (note the single quotes):

```
{if '{side_content_selectables:selected option="show_feed"}'}
    <p>show the feed</p>
{/if}
```

Maybe there's been a change in the plugin since this was originally posted, but I discovered that without those single quotes, EE will throw a PHP error if none of the checkboxes are checked.